# How do `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` avoid a leak in this case?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, race-condition

Typically a smart pointer (either strong or weak) will deallocate the control block when both the strong and weak refcounts reach 0.

I have a problem figuring out how this is achieved in the following scenario: Thread A holds a strong reference and Thread B holds a weak reference, both pointing to the same block.

Assuming the strong reference is in the process of being destroyed, and the strong refcount has reached 0, the reference destructor will invoke the destructor for the managed object. So far, so good.

But then it checks the weak refcount and decides based on that value, to deallocate the block.

Here is where I still see potential for a race between the weak reference in thread B and the strong reference in thread A to deallocate the block twice. The weak reference might decrease its weak refcount atomically to 0, but I don't see why the strong reference won't be able to see this 0 before the weak reference gets to deallocate, and deallocate again.

Comment: I don't think smart pointers guarantee any thread safety.  If you need that, you need to build something else to control access to the pointers.

Comment: @MarkRansom You're not allowed to access the same shared/weak_ptr object from different threads without external synchronization, but accesses to different such objects must work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you are imagining something like

```cpp
~shared_ptr() {
   if (--strong_ref == 0) {
       destroy_object();
       if (weak_ref == 0) {
           deallocate_block();
       }
   }
}
~weak_ptr() {
    if (--weak_ref == 0) {
        deallocate_block();
    }
}
```

which could indeed cause `deallocate_block()` to be called twice. Hence, it's not a correct implementation.

The trick is to have `shared_ptr` construction increment (and destruction decrement) both the strong and the weak reference counts:

```cpp
~shared_ptr() {
   if (--strong_ref == 0) {
       destroy_object();
   }
   if (--weak_ref == 0) {
       deallocate_block();
   }
}
```

With one `shared_ptr` and one `weak_ptr` outstanding, the weak count would be 2, not 1. When both are destroyed, `deallocate_block` will only be called once - by the destructor that decremented the weak count to zero.

As an optimization, we can have *all* outstanding `shared_ptr`s for a given control block share ownership of one increment of the weak count, in which case the destructor would look like:

```
~shared_ptr() {
   if (--strong_ref == 0) {
       destroy_object();
       if (--weak_ref == 0) {
           deallocate_block();
       }
   }
}
```

In this setup, if there is any shared_ptr outstanding then the weak count will be `(# of outstanding weak_ptrs) + 1`.

Comment: Usually, the two refcounts are called something like `strong_refcnt` and `total_refcnt`, making it clearer what is going on.  There's no explicit `weak_refcnt` as that is implicitly the difference between the other two.

Comment: Excellent explanation, apparently missed the fact that the strong references need at least one extra weak counter. Thus making the potential race condition impossible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The control block for `shared_ptr` is guaranteed thread-safe and no race exists between the destruction of a `shared_ptr` and any remaining `weak_ptr` instances.

In practical terms, this can be achieved by the control block implicitly treating itself as a weak reference. In other words, the weak count begins at 1. When the object is destroyed, the control block then also releases one more weak reference.

For instance, Microsoft's implementation goes like this:

```
class __declspec(novtable) _Ref_count_base { // common code for reference counting

    // ...

private:
    _Atomic_counter_t _Uses  = 1;
    _Atomic_counter_t _Weaks = 1;

public:
    void _Decref() noexcept { // decrement use count
        if (_MT_DECR(_Uses) == 0) {
            _Destroy();
            _Decwref();
        }
    }

    void _Decwref() noexcept { // decrement weak reference count
        if (_MT_DECR(_Weaks) == 0) {
            _Delete_this();
        }
    }

    // ...

};
```

Above, when `_Uses` reaches zero, the object is destroyed and then a weak reference is released. If that results in no weak references remaining, the control block is destroyed.

Comment: the promotion of a weak reference to a strong via lock is not relevant in this example, the question is about both the strong and weak references being destroyed and who gets to deallocate the control block (so that it happens exactly once)

Comment: It's simplest to think of it as _both_ strong and weak pointers have a strong reference to the control block, but only strong references will affect the target object's reference count. Therefore, the control block itself hangs around until no references to it remain, even if the object is long since gone. It does not matter which object is responsible for switching off the lights and locking the doors.

Comment: @lurscher I have updated the answer to demonstrate how this is achieved in practice without doubling the overhead of reference-counting.

Answer (score 1):

The weak counter isn't used to control allocation/deallocation of the pointee object. It's used to control allocation/deallocation of the pointer control block.

That is, with shared_ptr, you normally end up with a structure something like this:

[image]

Right now we have 2 `shared_ptr`s, so the ref count is 2. When it reaches 0, we destroy the `T` and the control block.

But then add in a couple of `weak_ptr`s:

[image]

This creates a bit of a problem. We want to delete the `T` when the ref count reaches 0. But we can't delete the control block when refs=0, because that would leave the two `weak_ptr`s with pointers that they "think" point to a control block, but the control block is now gone, so they have stale pointers.

So, we add a second ref count: one for the number of `shared_ptr`s, and one for the total of the `share_ptr`s and `weak_ptr`s. The first controls deletion of the `T`, and the second controls deletion of the control block itself.

[image]

Comment: And, in the case of `make_shared()` where the control block and `T` are combined in one memory allocation, what happens?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Comceptually, allocating a single block to contain both the control information and the T doesn't really change much. You basically allocate enough space for both, then construct objects into that space. You still destroy the T when the ref-count goes to 0, and the control block when the pointer count goes to 0. The sole difference is that you allocate the block with `::operator new`, release it with `::operator delete`, and don't actually release the memory until you destroy the control block.